# Android Spring Rest Client "exchange" creating the class (406 Not Acceptable)

Tags: android, json, parsing, resttemplate

I've implemented this example [Retrieving JSON data via HTTP GET](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/rest-template.html#d5e373)

Json response is something like this:

```
{"employees":[{"personName":"Albert","personSurname":"1stein","personNumber":"1","personMobile":"5555555","personId":"1234567890","personCompanyCode":"CC01"},
{"personName":"Albert","personSurname":"2stein","personNumber":"2","personMobile":"5555556","personId":"1234567891","personCompanyCode":"CC01"},
{"personName":"Albert","personSurname":"2stein","personNumber":"3","personMobile":"5555557","personId":"1234567892","personCompanyCode":"CC01"},
{"personName":"Albert","personSurname":"4stein","personNumber":"4","personMobile":"5555558","personId":"1234567893","personCompanyCode":"CC01"},
{"personName":"Albert","personSurname":"5stein","personNumber":"5","personMobile":"5555559","personId":"1234567894","personCompanyCode":"CC01"}],
"result":true,"message":"OK"}
```

I cannot use `StringHttpMessageConverter` because my data is huge (200,000 employee) It gives me an *OutOfMemoryError*.

I want to retrieve this data directly from json as in the example but it gives me *406 not acceptable error*.

myClass.java :

```
public class MyClass { private String personName; private String
personSurname; .. ..

(Setters and Getters) .. ..


}
```

I've tried the following methods, but no difference:

```
restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, myClass.class)
```

or

```
restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, myClass[].class)
```

What is the right way to get myClass objects from this json?

Comment: is your class name `myClass` or `MyClass` ? @serhat

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of the response from the web server? Is it `application/json`? What headers do you set for `requestEntity`? Is there something like `requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));` included?

Comment: Your JSON result does not consist of an array of `MyClass` elements alone. The array of `MyClass` elements can only be accessed by the `employees` field. So you have to create another class which contains something like `private MyClass[] employees;` and set this class as fourth parameter for the `exchange` method.

Comment: @Coder Android Studio will not allow myClass. So the mistake cannot be at that point.

Comment: @gus27 I've already added setAccept for application json. The second post of yours is the reason I think. I will apply Coder's answer and reply to that post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the child nodes directly instead of going through the parent node. Rest Template by default tries to convert the response JSON data into the class specified and will throw an error if it couldn't like in your case.

Here is the employee class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"personName",
"personSurname",
"personNumber",
"personMobile",
"personId",
"personCompanyCode"
})
public class Employee {

@JsonProperty("personName")
private String personName;
@JsonProperty("personSurname")
private String personSurname;
@JsonProperty("personNumber")
private String personNumber;
@JsonProperty("personMobile")
private String personMobile;
@JsonProperty("personId")
private String personId;
@JsonProperty("personCompanyCode")
private String personCompanyCode;

@JsonProperty("personName")
public String getPersonName() {
return personName;
}

@JsonProperty("personName")
public void setPersonName(String personName) {
this.personName = personName;
}

@JsonProperty("personSurname")
public String getPersonSurname() {
return personSurname;
}

@JsonProperty("personSurname")
public void setPersonSurname(String personSurname) {
this.personSurname = personSurname;
}

@JsonProperty("personNumber")
public String getPersonNumber() {
return personNumber;
}

@JsonProperty("personNumber")
public void setPersonNumber(String personNumber) {
this.personNumber = personNumber;
}

@JsonProperty("personMobile")
public String getPersonMobile() {
return personMobile;
}

@JsonProperty("personMobile")
public void setPersonMobile(String personMobile) {
this.personMobile = personMobile;
}

@JsonProperty("personId")
public String getPersonId() {
return personId;
}

@JsonProperty("personId")
public void setPersonId(String personId) {
this.personId = personId;
}

@JsonProperty("personCompanyCode")
public String getPersonCompanyCode() {
return personCompanyCode;
}

@JsonProperty("personCompanyCode")
public void setPersonCompanyCode(String personCompanyCode) {
this.personCompanyCode = personCompanyCode;
}

}
```

Here is the parent class which encompasses your JSON Response

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"employees",
"result",
"message"
})
public class EmployeeDataResponse {

@JsonProperty("employees")
private List<Employee> employees = null;
@JsonProperty("result")
private Boolean result;
@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;

@JsonProperty("employees")
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
return employees;
}

@JsonProperty("employees")
public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
this.employees = employees;
}

@JsonProperty("result")
public Boolean getResult() {
return result;
}

@JsonProperty("result")
public void setResult(Boolean result) {
this.result = result;
}

@JsonProperty("message")
public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

@JsonProperty("message")
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

}
```

In this case your rest call should be as follows

```
EmployeeDataResponse employeeDataResponse = restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, EmployeeDataResponse.class);
```

Let me know if you need clarification regarding the answer.

Comment: It works flawlessly. This will be a good example for the newbies like me. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!!